# Running multiple Asyntasks simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem that I cant understand it at all!. I have an `Asynctask` that connects to a web service and download some data.

But when I do this my other `Asynctasks` waits to this `Asynctask to finish his work even`Asynctasks`in other`Activities`!!. But I can't understand this.

How I can avoid this?. I was thinking that `Asynctasks` can run simultaneously but now it doesn't!. What is the  problem? It seems REST and downloading stream data blocks the entire app.

Comment: You are going to have to show us some code.  It is quite possible to run two or more async tasks simultaneously.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html - just read the documentation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running on Android 3.0 or later, and you're using the default implementation of `AsyncTask` (i.e. the one from the framework), it'll only execute a single task at a time. It is, however, possible to get parallel execution. See below.

**From the [documentation of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, `AsyncTasks` were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with `DONUT`, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `executoOnExecutor`

```
TheTask task = new TheTask();
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html